How to Find a Conformal Mapping from a Crescent-Shaped Region to an Annulus?

I am trying to find a conformal mapping from
$\{:∣∣<1\}\cap\{:|z−\frac{1}{2}∣>\frac{1}{2}\}$ onto an annulus.

This question is the very last  problem from an old complex analysis exam.
I do not have much experience with conformal maps. My first thought is a lost cause, I wanted something like this:

The boundary is off and it is almost impossible to find an explicit map.
Next I thought maybe we could try playing with $\log(z)$ (excluding the real axis from the domain) in the crescent shaped region.
The result is an "elipsoid looking" shape which has a $0$, $2\pi i$, $\pi i -\ln(2)$ and $\pi i +\ln(3/2)$ in the boundary. This also doens't seem very promissing.
What is a nice strategy to tackle this problem? I suspect Mobius transformations will be of no help  as it should map the circles onto circles and this doesn't happen in our figure.

Your go-to tool when dealing with shapes made out of circles should be Moebius transformations. Try starting with a Moebius transformation that sends the point where the bounding circles intersect to $\infty$...

@IzaakvanDongen, if we do that, I think our region will be mapped to a sector, which me may take a power of to yield a semi plane. This semi plane is conformally equivalent to a circle (which we could have maybe concluded directly using Riemann mapping theorem?). So it remains to map the circle onto an annulus. This seems equally hard to me. Am I overlooking something?

No, that's not quite right - you don't get a sector :). The two circles are sent to a pair of lines that intersect only at $\infty$, meaning they must be _____.... (By the way I strongly suspect that the point of this exercise is not to use the RMT - certainly that wouldn't have been allowed when I was taking complex analysis and answering questions like this)

Very nice! So we use Mobius and then $e^z$ which maps it into an annulus. Final question. Is there a nice way to see all of the strip with parallel lines is attained by our first map?

Exactly! Since we know the Moebius transformation sends the circles to two parallel lines, there are some "cheap" ways to see the region is sent to a strip. It depends a bit on the expected level of rigour. The region must be sent to one of the three regions into which the lines divide $\Bbb C$. You can see it's the strip by calculating the image of a single point in the region, or by observing that the strip is the only one that touches both lines. This is all because Moebius transformations are homeomorphisms of the Riemann sphere. If you like, feel free to self-answer this post BTW!

(So the fully formal fact I'm using is "if $f: X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism and $A \subseteq X$, then if $C \subseteq X \setminus A$ is a connected component of $X \setminus A$, then $f(C) \subseteq Y \setminus f(A)$ is a connected component of $Y \setminus f(A)$ and $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism $f: C \to f(C)$")

Slightly simpler: $z \mapsto 1/(1-z)$ maps $1 \to \infty$, so that the two boundary circles of
$$
D = \{ z: |z| < 1, |z - 1/2 | > 1/2 \}
$$
are mapped to lines which are orthogonal to the real axis, i.e. to the lines $\operatorname{Re}(w) = 1$ and $\operatorname{Re}(w) = 1/2$, respectively. Then $D$ is mapped to the strip
$$
 \{ w : 1/2 < \operatorname{Re}(w) < 1 \}
$$
so that $f(z) = \exp(1/(1-z))$ maps $D$ onto the annulus
$$
 \{ \zeta : e^{1/2} < |\zeta |  < e \} \, .
$$

I am indebted to Izaak van Dongen.
We want a Mobius transformation mapping: $(i,-1,1)\rightarrow (i,2i,\infty)$. The infinity condition implies we need something of the form $(az+b)/(z-1)$. Also, $ai+b=(i-1)i$ and $-a+b=-4i$ which gives us $a=1+2i$ and $b=1-2i$. So:
$$f(z)=\frac{(1+2i)z+1-2i}{z-1}$$
This maps our unitary circle to the line with $x=0$. Our second circle is mapped to the line passing through $f(0)=-1 + 2i$ and because it does not intersect our first line, it must be $x=-1$. Because homeomorphism preserve path connected regions, then $f(D)=\{z\: : \: -1<\text{Real}(z)<0\}$. Finally, taking $e^z$ yields an annulus with inner radius $e^{-1}$ and outter radius $1$. Our final map is:
$$g(z)=e^{\frac{(1+2i)z+1-2i}{z-1}}$$

I know that the conformal image of a simply connected region is simply connected.  Maybe I'm on the fence right now, but isn't ${z:∣z∣<1}\cap {z: |z−1/2∣>1/2}$ simply connected?

Indeed, if there were a conformal mapping (with inverse) it would preserve simple connectedness. But in this case our map is only surjective. :)

Ah, I see, thanks!

That is a very nice question. Thank you for asking it.
